# How to set different margin-top for span elements?

Tags: html, css

I would like to have different margin for span elements. E.g., `margin-top: 25px` should be for the first span element and `margin-top: 15px` should be for the second element :

```html
    <div style="background: green">
       <span style="display: inline-block; margin-top: 25px;">1</span>
       <span style="display: inline-block; margin-top: 15px;">2</span>
    </div>
```

However, the second `span` has `margin-top: 25px`.

Is it possible to set different `margin-top` for both `span` elements?

Comment: What makes you think they don't have that now?

Comment: they both stand on the same baseline, you may reset vertical-align or use float or flex

Comment: @G-Cyr could you show, please, code with using `flex`?

Comment: just add display:flex to the parent (green bg) . usefull link https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @G-Cyr thank you very much!:) it works! I am really shamed! Upvoted!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put `vertical-align: top`. By default `inline-block` elements will sink to the level of their siblings.

Comment: thank you very much! It works! I'll mark you reply as answer

Answer (score 2):

Just to show they do have I added a border and put a flex display on the container thing.  This also depends on how you want it visually.  I added a second example where it moves without changing the border contained size.

```css
.thing {
  display: flex;
  background: green
}

.thing-span {
  display: inline-block;
  border: yellow 1px solid;
}

.thing-span.one {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.thing-span.two {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="thing">
  <span class="thing-span one">1</span>
  <span class ="thing-span two">2</span>
</div>
```

another way

```css
.thing {
  
  background: green
}

.thing-span {
  display: inline-block;
  border: yellow 1px solid;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.thing-span.one {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.thing-span.two {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="thing">
  <span class="thing-span one">1</span>
  <span class ="thing-span two">2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: no need of inline-block for the span if the parent is a flex box ;)

Comment: @G-Cyr - yes, but I wanted to show the second example in comparison visually - which may impact the choice of how this might be done. And, that is what the OP had which may have other impact.

Comment: for a demo, you could set the display:flex on hover, so he can see what is the difference in between the 2 layout display ;)

Comment: do many choices, so little time :)